# Best way to implement expandable recycler android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Any suggestion about implementing the recycler view with expandable items after some search only found there's an only expandable list based on the list view so if there are new things based on the Recycler view and recycler adapter also I give[thoughtbot expandable-recycler-view](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)a try but it doesn't work with the notifyDataSetChanged Thanks on advanced.